# Are pulation squares "weak equivalences"?

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Let $\cal C$ a category where a square is a pullback if and only if it is a pushout.

Is there a model structure on $\cal C^\to$ (the category of arrows of $\cal C$) where the class of weak equivalences is given by pullback squares? I am obviously motivated by the fact that the 2-out-of-3 property, and even closure under retracts, hold for those squares.

**Edit:** The question was initially posed in a different way, which in fact does not allow to prove that the 2-out-3 property holds: if you suppose that a square is a pb iff is a po, then in a double square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
A&\to&B&\to&C\\
\downarrow&\boxed{a}&\downarrow&\boxed{b}&\downarrow\\
A'&\to&B'&\to&C'
\end{array}
$$
a wise application of the pasting lemma (either in the case with pullbacks, or int e case with pushouts) gives you what you need.

Comment: Is it obvious that it has the 2-out-of-3 property? Pullbacks and pushouts each have (a different) half of the 2-out-of-3 property...

Comment: Yeah, you're right: I have to ask that in $\cal C$ pullbacks and pushouts coincide (is there a name for such categories?).

Comment: The only categories I know with this property are the empty category and the trivial category $\mathbb{1}$. $\mathbf{Set}$ doesn't have this property, $\mathbf{Ab}$ doesn't have this property, most lattices don't have this property, etc.

Comment: Any stable $\infty$-category in the sense of Lurie has this property: see Prop.4.4 here http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608228v5.pdf

Comment: $\infty$-categories are not categories: for example, the category of chain complexes doesn't have the required property, even though the corresponding $\infty$-category is a stable $\infty$-category.